# after re-install angular/cli: Module build failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'newLine' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, npm, angular-cli

I have an angular-2 app.

I try to run `ng serve` but get this error:

```
ERROR in ./src/main.ts
Module build failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'newLine' of undefined
    at Object.getNewLineCharacter (/Users/eladb/WorkspaceQa/Gasolina/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:8062:20)
    at Object.createCompilerHost (/Users/eladb/WorkspaceQa/Gasolina/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:44978:26)
    at Object.ngcLoader (/Users/eladb/WorkspaceQa/Gasolina/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/loader.js:170:31)
 @ multi webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:4200 ./src/main.ts

ERROR in ./src/polyfills.ts
Module build failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'newLine' of undefined
    at Object.getNewLineCharacter (/Users/eladb/WorkspaceQa/Gasolina/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:8062:20)
    at Object.createCompilerHost (/Users/eladb/WorkspaceQa/Gasolina/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:44978:26)
    at Object.ngcLoader (/Users/eladb/WorkspaceQa/Gasolina/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/loader.js:170:31)
 @ multi ./src/polyfills.ts
webpack: Failed to compile.
```

I have tried to uninstall and re-install angular/cli locally and globally.

but i still get this error.

here is my `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "x",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false",
    "e2e": "protractor",
    "posttest": "node_modules/.bin/remap-istanbul -i coverage/coverage.json -o coverage/html-report -t html",
    "coverage": "http-server -c-1 -o -p 9876 ./coverage"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.4.7",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.4.7",
    "@angular/core": "^2.4.7",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.4.7",
    "@angular/http": "^2.4.7",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.4.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.4.7",
    "@angular/router": "^3.4.7",
    "ng2-tabs": "^0.0.11",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "ng2-bootstrap": "^1.3.3",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.1",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.4.7",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.42",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0-beta.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage": "^1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
    "remap-istanbul": "^0.9.5",
    "karma-istanbul-threshold": "^1.2.2",
    "protractor": "~4.0.13",
    "ts-node": "1.2.1",
    "tslint": "^4.3.0",
    "typescript": "~2.0.3"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of CLI are you using? This all looks outdated

This could help :

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Official docs: https://cli.angular.io/

Then, generate new project: `ng new myapp`

Comment: I did as you suggested, I tried to run `ng serve` and got the same error. Reg my versions: ➜  `Your global Angular CLI version (1.4.9) is greater than your local
version (1.2.0). The local Angular CLI version is used.`

Comment: now i get this error: `has no exported member 'node_modules/ng2-bootstrap/dropdown/index"' has no exported member 'DropdownModule'.`

Comment: This is probably an issue with your import of *ng2-bootstrap*, which by the way has been renamed *ngx-bootstrap*. You should check the official docs: https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/